# make all values but one in large raster file 0

Tags: bash, raster, gdal

I have a large raster file downloaded from Earth Engine. I want to turn it to a boolean file, keeping only one value (13) and make all other values either NA or 0. The file is so large it crashes QGIS and ArcMap when I try to process it, is there a way to do this using GDAL or bash? The file is a tif file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With R you can do

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
r <- raster("input.tif")
x <- calc(r, function(i){ i==13 }, filename="output.tif", datatype="INT1U")
```

Or use `raster::reclassify`

Comment: I ended up using this solution because I ran into errors that I couldn't fix with the other two, even though they answer the question I asked, I couldn't implement them because of a bad homebrew/python installation, and because of the 32-bit processing problem. I am sourcing the R code from terminal over a bunch of tiff images and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Make a test image at the command line - value 13 in the middle, red and blue around that:

```
convert -size 30x20 xc:"gray(13)"  \
   -bordercolor red  -border 10    \
   -bordercolor blue -border 10 start.tif
```

[image]

Now fill with black, everything that is not value 13:

```
convert start.tif -fill black +opaque "gray(13)" result.tif
```

Or, somewhat easier to see - fill everything that is not value 13 with cyan and change everything that is value 13 to yellow:

```
convert start.tif                  \
   -fill cyan   +opaque "gray(13)" \
   -fill yellow -opaque "gray(13)" result.tif
```

[image]

Comment: Any insights as to memory requirements? I imagine it still needs to load the entire file into memory.

Comment: @tripleee It takes 21MB for a 1000x1000 colour TIF, less if you make it 8-bit rather than 16-bit. If I **had** to do it with minimal memory, I would look to `vips` or **ImageMagick**'s `stream` command, or a line-by-line based C program using `libtiff`.

Comment: Thanks, up to the OP really to clarify what they mean by "big".

Comment: @tripleee Standard TIFFs use 32-bit offsets, so are limited to 4GB anyway - unless OP is using the rather rare `BigTIFF`.

Comment: Seems like the solution I'm looking for, but I'm getting this error: convert: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples.

Comment: I suspect that means you have got a Q16 version of **ImageMagick** which uses 16-bit quantisation and can't hold 32-bit values. I think you need to install an HDRI version of **ImageMagick**. What platform are you on, btw? I was expecting your data to be single channel (grey) 8/16 bit because you said you wanted `value 13` not `value 13.0` (implying float) nor `value (13,13,13)` (implying 3-channel image). What is your image? Greyscale or colour? What dimensions?

Comment: I´m on OS 10.12. I use the image as single band pseudo-color. It´s the exported file from Earth Engine, I think it is value 13.0, but I´m not sure.

Comment: I presume you mean `OS X/macOS`. If so, you would install **ImageMagick** using **homebrew** with `brew install imagemagick --with-hdri`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a gdal solution:

Your input is `input.tif`:

`gdal_calc.py --calc="A==13" -A input.tif --type=Byte --outfile=output.tif`

Comment: I think OP has floats in his image rather than unsigned chars, so I think you'd need `--type= Float32` instead. Also, not sure how the mathematical comparison works with floats - you may need to allow for `12.99872` or `13.00012` or somesuch.

Comment: Doesn't the OP want a boolean raster? That's why I set it to Byte

Comment: Oh, I was assuming that was the input file type - I don't know GDAL - so I may be completely wrong :-) Apologies if so!

Comment: No worries - the input DT is determined by gdal, and if you don't specifically add an output datatype, it'll be automatically set equal to the input